# How can I get users to select multiple options as input within a facebook messenger chatbot?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I am working on a form-fill bot, which takes takes user input in free text format, throws 3-4 relevant set of questions and give the relevant search results from the website.
In this process, how can I collect information from users for questions where answers can be more than one.

For Example: What are the list of languages you are fluent in?
[] English [] French [] Hindi [] Urdu

How can I fill more than one option? In conventional forms, we user checkboxes. But how to do it in FB messenger.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I want same , Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no such support for it, but a work around would be using list template with buttons there corresponding payloads. You can send a list of languages to render with two buttons yes/no in order to take user input. Here is the link to docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/list-template